# Updating invalid json output to make it valid from a file

Tags: json, bash

I have the following data that I already insert in a file called `file.json`:

```
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169149"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169159"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 10,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169326"
}
```

To be specific, this is how I added it using jq every time I run the `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# I run this script 3 times to insert into file.json:

#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 17
#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 17
#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 10

OUTPUT='file.json'
JSON_OUTPUT='data:{}'

IP="$1"
TEST_COUNT="$2"

JSON_OUTPUT=$(jq \
  --arg ip "${IP}" \
  --argjson tested_count "${TEST_COUNT}" \
  --arg last_scan_date "$(date +%s)" \
  '{ip: $ip, tested_count: $tested_count, last_scan_date: $last_scan_date}' <<<"${JSON_OUTPUT}")

# Write the output to the file
echo "${JSON_OUTPUT}" >>"${OUTPUT}"
```

Now, based on the output from `file.json` it looks like it is not a valid json. So, my aim is to transform that into a valid json that looks like below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "tested_count": 17,
      "last_scan_date": "1673169149"
    },
    {
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "tested_count": 17,
      "last_scan_date": "1673169159"
    },
    {
      "ip": "1.1.1.1",
      "tested_count": 10,
      "last_scan_date": "1673169326"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen an example of this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569876/add-json-objects-to-array-using-jq) but the example shown there is using a looping method which is not necessary in my case as my json data is dynamically added each time the `script.sh` above run.

What I have tried so far is using an update `inputs` filter like this but obviously, this does not fix the json as a valid syntax.

```
echo "$json_query" | jq -n '.data |= [inputs]' >> file.json
```

Comment: just fix your `script.sh` so it could write each object on a single line. That lines are then easily parsed by `jq`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest do you mean that I fix it in bash way or using jq? I tried the update command |= but doesn't seems to work. Also, I have no idea if the update command should be used here to insert that top level object. That's why I thought it would be better to modify the final output file.json.

Comment: literally: make the actions that will ensure "each object on a single line"

Comment: The code you provide does not work and does certainly not produce what you pretend it does. Did you copy it without really understanding how it works?

Comment: @LéaGris I think it was a typo at this line `OUTPUT=`file.json``. It is fixed now. The step to reproduce is written from scratch that I try to narrow it as a simple example from my 10k line of codes. So, I did not copy this question from somewhere else. This is my first question that get downvoted maybe I took longer to fix the step to reproduce as it was late night when I posted this question. Thank you.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I still don't get what you mean there ... As stated in the original question, I only want to change the final output `from a file` and not to fix the other part of the script (the .sh script).  The `script.sh` I provided in the question is just an example how the output was generated and I'm only interested to change the final output (file.json) to be valid. Maybe I should not have included that optional `script.sh` there @Walter A has answered the question perfectly following the original question and I believe this question has never been asked in SO following this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `sed`:

```
echo '{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169149"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 17,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169159"
}
{
  "ip": "1.1.1.1",
  "tested_count": 10,
  "last_scan_date": "1673169326"
}' | sed 's/}/},/;s/^/    /; 1 s/^/{\n  "data": [\n/; $ s/,/\n  ]\n}/'
```

Comment: @LéaGris I upvoted your answer, I agree with your reason. And since OP is already using `jq`, (s)he should fix `script.sh`. I just provided my answer for the case that OP doesn't want or can (change process in company) update the `script.sh`. And I am not as good in `jq` as you are.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it properly with `jq`.

I added lots of comments for both the shell and the jq script parts.
Don't hesitate to question me in comments if something is unclear, anyway. That would be preferable to blindly copying code.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 17
#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 17
#./script.sh 1.1.1.1 10

# No reason to use ALL_CAPS variable names unless these are environment
output_file='file.json'

# ${var:?} expansion means var is mandatory and it will error if not provided
arg_ip="${1:?}"
arg_test_count="${2:?}"

# If output file does not exist
if ! [ -f "${output_file}" ]; then
  # Initializes it with object of empty JSON data array
  jq --null-input '{"data":[]}' > "${output_file}"
fi

# Buffer the output of processing updated JSON data
json_buffer=$(
  jq \
    --arg arg_ip "${arg_ip}" \
    --argjson tested_count "${arg_test_count}" \
    '
# Add new object entry to the data array
.data += [{
  "arg_ip": $arg_ip,
  "tested_count": $tested_count,
  "last_scan_date": now|rint # builtin jq timestamp integer part
}]
' "${output_file}"
)

# Write the buffer content back to the file
# printf '%s\n' will preserve the buffer content
# and restores the trailing newline at end of file
printf '%s\n' "${json_buffer}" > "${output_file}"
```

Comment: Hai @Lea Gris thanks for providing this solution. I accepted Walter's answer because it followed what I asked originally as I only wanted to `modify the final output`. When I wrote the question (I did not intend to provide the script as it was just an optional script). and the question starts with the following: `Now, based on the output from file.json ....` I know what I did there might not be the best. Your answer looks better too but I have to accept the answer that follow my original question. Thank you for details explanation for each code comments. You are a good instructor.

Comment: My `jq` doesn't support `now|rint`, can I use `now|floor`?

Comment: @WalterA You can definitely use `floor`.

Comment: `$arg_ip`, and `$tested_count` are in single quotes and don't get evaluated. Did you mean `.data += [{ "arg_ip": "'"$arg_ip"'", "tested_count": "'"$arg_test_count"'", "last_scan_date": now|floor }]` ?

Comment: @WalterA they are evaluated internally by jq as respective JSON string and number from the `--arg arg_ip "${arg_ip}"` and the `--argjson tested_count "${arg_test_count}"` aruments to jq.